# CURL Not Following Redirect

Tags: shell, curl

I am trying to setup a page that redirects to an sh file so I don't have to lookup the actual URL when I need it, but I can't get curl to follow the redirect even when using `-L`. what am I doing wrong? The link I am using to redirect is [here](https://hbiede.com/defaults)

Comment: What are you sending as the "redirect" page?  A HTTP 301 response with a Location header is required.

Comment: It would help if you included an (edited) output of `curl -L -v http://your_url -o /dev/null` into your question.

Answer (score 1):

Your link is using a html redirect instead of a http redirect so here is a dirty hack;

```
URL=$(curl -s https://hbiede.com/defaults | grep http | perl -pe 's/.*=(http)/$1/g;s/".*//g')
curl -s "$URL" > defaults.sh
```